# How to add an application to startup using installer?

Tags: .net, setup-project

I am making an installer using "setup" project in VS2005. I want the project output - application.exe to be added to startup by modifying this registry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.
How can I do in the setup project.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Right click setup project in Solution Explorer, choose View/Registry and in the new window that will popup set all the registry keys you need. You can do similar things to the file system and choose where each file from your application will be placed and so on.